# Converting a file of dates into unix time with awk

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file that contains dates and lat longs and I want to convert the dates that are in UTC to unix time. I decided to use the unix date function within an awk script to do this. I tried:

```
awk 'BEGIN {t=$3; c="date -j -f %Y%j%H%M%S "t" +%s"; c|getline; close( c ); print $1, $2, c; }' test.txt
```

where `t` is the third row in my file and is in the format 2014182120311. I am new to awk/scripting and not sure if it is possible to imbed an awk variable into a unix command inside an awk line.

When I run the script I get the error:

```
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
        [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

So I think I am not defining "t" properly. Any help is much appreciated!

On a side note- I have tried mktime and the other awk time functions but they do not work for me I believe because I do not have gawk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you not have the option of installing `gawk`? You'll thank yourself later (e.g. see [Converting list of dates from a file to timestamp with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63815992/1745001)).

The `BEGIN` section is executed before any file is opened, so `$3` (the 3rd field of the current record read from the current file) has no meaning in that section and so `t=$3` just sets the variable `t` to the null string.

You don't want to print the command, c, you want to print the result of executing the command as read by `getline` but when you use undirected `getline` it overwrites $0, $1, etc. so you should save the result in a var (see http://awk.info/?tip/getline).

You probably want something like this:

```
awk '{
    cmd = "date -j -f %Y%j%H%M%S " $3 " +%s"
    if ( (cmd | getline time) > 0 ) {
        print $1, $2, time
    }
    close(cmd)
}' test.txt
```

but if not, post some sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: Your above example gives the result I was looking for- the logic makes a lot more sense this way. Will look into installing gawk. Thanks!